# Mock constant in python unit test doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking

I'm trying to mock a constant in my python unit test.

I've a module called *settings.py* which contains a set of constants, in particular I've this one:

```
REL_PATH = "my/path/{}/file.csv"
```

Then in another module I've this function which use REL_PATH variable like this:

```
from path.for.REL_PATH.setting import REL_PATH

def create_csv(missing_path_here):
    columns = ["col_a", "col_b", ...]
    empty_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
    Writer(empty_df, REL_PATH.format(missing_path_here)).write_csv()
```

In my unit test I've the following code:

```
class TestCreateAnomaliesRepositoryCsv(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch("path.for.setting.REL_PATH", "another/custom/path/file.csv")
    def test_create_anomalies_repository_csv(self):
         create_csv(missing_path_here="test")
```

I expect that in this way the csv file will be created under "another/custom/path/" path, but still the csv file is created in the original directory.

I've also tried to do like this:

```
def test_create_anomalies_repository_csv(self):
    with path("path.for.setting.REL_PATH", "another/custom/path/file.csv")
        create_csv(missing_path_here="test")
```

but the final result is the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It depends on how you import `REL_PATH` in your tested code. If you import it using `from .. import REL_PATH`, you have to patch `REL_PATH` in _that_ module - check [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6).

Comment: Thank you so much @MrBeanBremen! if you want to add an answer i will mark it as correct!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If patching an object, you have to always patch the object as used in the module, e.g. if you have imported it in the form: `from x import y` in your module `module`, you have to patch `module.y` instead of `x.y`. This is described in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6), and there is a nice [blog post](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201908/why_your_mock_doesnt_work.html) by Ned Batchelder describing the problem in more detail. In your case you need:

```python
@patch("path.to.using_module.REL_PATH", "another/custom/path/file.csv")
def test_create_anomalies_repository_csv(self):
     create_csv(missing_path_here="test")
```

provided that `path.to.using_module.py` imports the constant like this:

```python
from path.for.setting import REL_PATH
```

The other variant you tried is equivalent and will also work:

```python
def test_create_anomalies_repository_csv(self):
    with path("path.to.using_module.REL_PATH", "another/custom/path/file.csv")
        create_csv(missing_path_here="test")
```

To summarize, you always have to check how the object to use is imported. There are basically two cases:

- the object is imported in `sut.py` like `import module` or `import module.object` - in this case it can be patched as `module.object`
- the object is imported in `sut.py` like `from module import object` - in this case `sut.py` uses a local reference to refer to the object, and the patching shall be done for `sut.object`