# Python: issues when mocking randint

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

Having a hard time understanding why my randint mock is not working. Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong, and how to fix that? Tried several different approaches I looked up online, but with a pdb I could see the `randint(0, 100)` call is not being mocked.

Here is the `src/game.py` file:

```
from src.player import Player
from random import randint
from time import sleep


class Game:
... 
    def attack(self, attacker, defender):
        luck_factor = randint(0, 100)
        damage_impact = attacker.energy_hit(luck_factor)
        defender.energy -= damage_impact
        print(f"{attacker.name} atacou {defender.name}")
        print(f"NOME_DO_FATOR_SORTE - {damage_impact} HP")
```

And here is the `tests/test_game_units.py` file:

```
from src.game import Game
from src.player import Player
from unittest.mock import patch


class TestGame:
    def setup_class(self):
        self.game = Game()
...                                                     

    @patch("random.randint")
    def test_attack(self, mock_random_value):
        mock_random_value.return_value = 42

        new_game = Game()
        attacker = Player(name="Batman", energy=100, power=100)
        defender = Player(name="Superman", energy=100, power=100)
        new_game.attack(attacker, defender)

        assert defender.energy == 67, "Expects the defender to have it's energy lowered to 67"
        assert attacker.energy == 100, "Expects the attacker to still have full energy (100)"
```

Comment: Looks like you are not patching the `randint` used by your module. I just [answered a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62232014/12480730), please check the links I posted there.

Comment: Thanks @MrBeanBremen! Got it working now. Maybe I had some pycache issue, as I've tried with "src.game.randint" and I got an error saying "src.game" wasn't a module.

Comment: Ah ok, so you did it correctly the first time :) Glad you could solve it.