# python unittest error and using patch from unittest.mock

Tags: python-unittest

I have two python files the first one is named `employee.py` and this is its **code**

```
import requests


class Employee:
    """A sample Employee class"""

    raise_amt = 1.05

    def __init__(self, first, last, pay):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay

    @property
    def email(self):
        return '{}.{}@email.com'.format(self.first, self.last)

    @property
    def fullname(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first, self.last)

    def apply_raise(self):
        self.pay = int(self.pay * self.raise_amt)


     def monthly_schedule(self, month):
         response = requests.get(f'http://company.com/{self.last}/{month}')
      
         if response.ok:
             return response.text
         else:
             return 'Bad Response!'
```

The other file is named `test_employee.py`
and this is its **code**

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

from employee import Employee


class TestEmployee(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod

    def setUpClass(cls):
        print('setupClass')

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        print('teardownClass')

    def setUp(self):
        print('setUp')
        self.emp_1 = Employee('Corey', 'Schafer', 50000)
        self.emp_2 = Employee('Sue', 'Smith', 60000)

    def tearDown(self):
        print('tearDown\n')

    def test_email(self):
        print('test_email')
        self.assertEqual(self.emp_1.email, 'Corey.Schafer@email.com')
        self.assertEqual(self.emp_2.email, 'Sue.Smith@email.com')

        self.emp_1.first = 'John'
        self.emp_2.first = 'Jane'

        self.assertEqual(self.emp_1.email, 'John.Schafer@email.com')
        self.assertEqual(self.emp_2.email, 'Jane.Smith@email.com')

    def test_fullname(self):
        print('test_fullname')
        self.assertEqual(self.emp_1.fullname, 'Corey Schafer')
        self.assertEqual(self.emp_2.fullname, 'Sue Smith')

        self.emp_1.first = 'John'
        self.emp_2.first = 'Jane'

        self.assertEqual(self.emp_1.fullname, 'John Schafer')
        self.assertEqual(self.emp_2.fullname, 'Jane Smith')

    def test_apply_raise(self):
        print('test_apply_raise')
        self.emp_1.apply_raise()
        self.emp_2.apply_raise()

        self.assertEqual(self.emp_1.pay, 52500)
        self.assertEqual(self.emp_2.pay, 63000)

    def test_monthly_schedule(self):
        with patch('employee.requests.get') as mocked_get:

            mocked_get.return_value.ok = True
            mocked_get.return_value.text = 'Success'

            schedule = self.emp_1.monthly_schedule('May')

            mocked_get.assert_called_with('http://company.com/Schafer/May')

            self.assertEqual(schedule,'Success')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

when I run `test_employee.py`, I get this error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'employee.requests'; 'employee' is not a package
```

The code runs well if you delete the function **test_monthly_schedule** from **test_employee.py**
and delete **monthly_schedule** from **employee.py**
also I do not know if that will make a difference, but I use python 3.8. Also, I'm using Mac

Comment: Just patch `requests` instead of `employee.requests`, just like it is imported.

Comment: Thank you, it worked.But, can you help me understand why? @MrBeanBremen

Comment: Please check my recent [answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62232014/12480730) that has a couple of helpful links.