# Issue with mocking another module intermediate functions in python

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

My project folder structure:

```
myproject

   utilities--encrypt_decrypt_util -- encrypt()
   src --sample.py
   tests --sample_test2.py
```

*src/sample.py:*

```py
from utilities.encrypt_decrypt_util import encrypt

def m1():
    print('from m1 method')
    encr_pwd=encrypt('SGu2s2RFT')
    print(encr_pwd)
```

*test/sample_test2.py:*

```py
from src.sample import m1
from mock import patch

def encrypt(password):
    print('its mock...')
    return 'encryptedpassword'

@patch('utilities.encrypt_decrypt_util.encrypt')
def test_mytst2(mock_m2):
    print('From test_mytst2 method')
    mock_m2.return_value= encrypt('password')
    print(m1())
```

*utilities/encrypt_decrypt_util.py*

```py
def encrypt(plain_text_pwd: str) -> bytes:
    #some code here
    return encrypted_password
```

When I execute `pytest test_mytst2`, the `encrypt` method shall be mocked, but the original method from `utils` is called instead.
Could you please help to understand what is the issue.

Comment: You should patch the module as imported, e.g. `@patch('src.sample.encrypt')`. See for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62232014/12480730).

Comment: @MrBeanBremen is right, I just tried that and it works, thank you. I just wanted to comment that if you use a debug tool when executing your test, you can see that the mock object you created has the returned value correctly assigned but it's never called, that could have given you a hint. 

Also, consider using [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) or some similar module for testing instead of prints, you would find it very useful. I recommend you this [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FxSsnHeWQBY).